# PHP's json_decode behaves differently on different servers

Tags: php

I'm setting up a new server, and have found that this snippet of code behaves differently in each setup:

```
function isJson($string) {
    json_decode($string);
    return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}

echo isJson("2014-04-21") ? "is json" : "is not json";
```

The old server has:

- PHP 5.5.5
- json support  enabled
- json version  1.2.1
- Result: "is not json"
- Result of var_dump(json_decode("2014-04-21")): NULL

The new server has:

- PHP 5.5.11
- json support  enabled
- json version  1.3.2
- JSON-C version (bundled)  0.11
- Result: "is json"
- Result of var_dump(json_decode("2014-04-21")): int(2014)

I'd appreciate any pointers on *why* this difference is happening or *where* to look to find out why this difference is happening.

Comment: What does `json_decode()` return in 5.5.11?

Comment: Can you print_r(json_decode($string))? This won't help but I'm curious what is result of this :)

Comment: One problem is that json_last_error() returns the *last* error. so if you call json_decode("garbage") and then json_decode("[1,2]") the last json_decode call was fine because "[1,2]" is proper JSON, but the last error is JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX, because "garbage" is not proper JSON.

Comment: I don't think so. The documentation says it's supposed to return the error (if any) of the last JSON parse.

Comment: @Michael nope on correct json it changes last error to 0(JSON_ERROR_NONE)

Comment: anyhow... the solution is to just check the return value of json_decode()

Comment: just saw the latest edit... interesting. for me, in PHP 5.3.28, `json_decode("2014-04-04") => NULL`

Comment: It looks like a bug. What are you doing that depends on being able to validate JSON, maybe there's some alternative solution?

Comment: Wait a second im installing php 5.6 :)

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, maybe could get away with checking if json_decode($str, true) returns an array.

Comment: sorry you had to wait. compilation takes time. php 5.6-alpha, json 1.2.1 (without json-c). Invalid json. I think you should report this to https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @mleko: I appreciate you checking that out.  I plan on submitting when I get back.

Comment: @Michael How would checking the result of json_decode detect `json_decode("2014")` vs `json_decode("2014-04-21")`? (Neither are actually *valid* JSON, per ["JSON text is a serialized object or array: JSON-text = object / array"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).)

Comment: well. this is just a PHP bug! the PHP docs say that json_decode() will return NULL if the string is not valid JSON. If json_decode() returns non-NULL then the algorithm has decided that the string is valid JSON and so json_last_error will say that everything is okay.

Comment: @Michael I agree with that, but the solution of "just check the return value of json_decode()" (or really, the approach that *should* work) .. doesn't handle this particular [bug] case as the question demonstrates :|

Comment: yeah, I think a solution would be to use a different version of PHP which doesn't have this bug, and in the meantime to file a bug report :-/ i know its a shitty situation, but what else do you want to do? you could write your own json_decode() function of course and use that instead. but if you have third-party code in your project you have the problem that you would need to patch that code too.

Comment: FWIW, I think the "correct solution" is to check to ensure if the result is an array - if it is, valid. If not, invalid. This is because *valid* JSON text must have a top-level JSON Array/JSON Object. After these changes, the differences between servers (additional bug or not) should "go away" in actual usage.

Answer (score 1):

That's obviously a bug in PHP :-/

#### Old answer:

It is much easier...

```
function isJson($string) {
    return json_decode($string) !== NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear this will fix it. If it's not detecting the error, it might return what it thinks the JSON represents.

Comment: well, then its a bug in PHP

Comment: Take a look at his updated question, it's returning `2014` in the `is json` case.